# shortcode from Custom post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, shortcode

I want to show my custom post using shortcode

my custom post code is below-

/*Custom Post*/

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'service_items',
array(
'labels' => array(
'name' => __( 'Service Items' ),
'singular_name' => __( 'Service Items' ),
'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Service Items' ),
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Service Items' ),
'new_item' => __( 'New Service Items' ),
'view_item' => __( 'View Service Items' ),
'not_found' => __( 'Sorry, we couldn\'t find the Service Items you are looking for.' )
),
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => true,
'menu_position' => 14,
'has_archive' => false,
'hierarchical' => false,
'capability_type' => 'page',
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'custompost_id' ),
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields','thumbnail' )
)
);
}
```

And Shortcode code is below -

```
function service_item_shortcode() {
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'service_items',
'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page'=> -1
);

$service_items = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $service_items->have_posts() ):
while ( $service_items->have_posts() ) : $service_items->the_post();
$service_output = '<div class="span3 serv">';
$service_output .='<div class="serv-img">' ; 
$service_output .=get_the_post_thumbnail( $service_items->post->ID, service-image) ; 
$service_output .='</div>'; 
$service_output .= '<h3>' . get_the_title() . '</h3> ';
$service_output .= '<p>' . get_the_content() . '</p> ';
$service_output .= '</div>';
endwhile;
endif;

return $service_output;
}

add_shortcode( 'service_item', 'service_item_shortcode' );
```

I want to show on my post 4 custom post items per page.
But when I put [service-item] shortcode output only show 1 post.

I need 4 post per page. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the output from all posts in a variable, instead of resetting the variable on each iteration. To do this, define an empty variable before the loop, and simply add to it all of the output of each post. Here is the changed code that should work for you (untested):

```
function service_item_shortcode() {
    $service_output = '';

    $paged = !empty($_GET['service_item_page']) ? absint($_GET['service_item_page']) : 1;
    if (!$paged) {
        $paged = 1;
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'service_items',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page'=> 4,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    $service_items = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $service_items->have_posts() ):
        while ( $service_items->have_posts() ) : $service_items->the_post();
            $service_output .= '<div class="span3 serv">';
            $service_output .= '<div class="serv-img">' ; 
            $service_output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'service-image'); 
            $service_output .= '</div>'; 
            $service_output .= '<h3>' . get_the_title() . '</h3> ';
            $service_output .= '<p>' . get_the_content() . '</p> ';
            $service_output .= '</div>';
        endwhile;
    endif;

    if ($service_items->max_num_pages > 1) {
        $service_output .= '<div class="pagination">';
        for($i = 1; $i <= $service_items->max_num_pages; $i++) {
            $service_output .= '<a href="' . add_query_arg('service_item_page', $i) . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
        }
        $service_output .= '</div>';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $service_output;
}

add_shortcode( 'service_item', 'service_item_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But it not work correctly. It show every item many times like My four item is wordpress, Html, Design and Css, Your code result show each item many times (which I put "posts_per_page value")

Comment: I've edited the code above - it now contains pagination links, and displays 4 products per page, ordered by their post date in descending order. It has been tested and works correctly in my installation. Feel free to try it out.

Comment: Output is same. Each item show four times. No pagination show.

Comment: I have tested this code with my post type and it works correctly. So it seems that there is something else on your side that is unknown for me. Can you please post some more code? For example, can you post the register_post_type() code that you're using to create the custom post type?

Comment: I already post custom post type code above. Please see my question starting option.

Comment: I've just tested the shortcode I posted, along with your code for the custom post type registration, and it worked correctly when i use the [service-item] shortcode anywhere in my page/post content. Pagination works properly, and items are displayed properly, 4 different items per page. Therefore there must be some other code that conflicts with your query. Do you have any theme functions hooked on the pre_get_posts hook or any other query-related hooks? Do you have any plugins enabled that might interfere with your custom WP_Query?